# Kernel 5.3 on AMD Chipset

Tags: boot, debian, linux-kernel, compile, kernel-module

currently I use my own compiled Kernel Since some mounth without any big issues, but since the Release 5.3 some physical Servers with AMD Chipset won't boot anymore, my last Kernel Vers. is 5.2.8 without any Problems. (Config still same)

The Kernel 5.3 works on my Host PC with B350 Chipset & Ryzen 1700 & KVM + VirtualBox Maschines except both Servers with older AMD Chipset.

1. The first Server is an AsRock A68N with AMD A4-5050 with 3 VMs on
   Kernel 5.3 (VBOX)
2. The second is a newer ITX Board with integrated CPU too a
   Biostar A10N-8800E | AMD FX-8800P CPU, without any running VMs.

On all Systems running Debian SID, but the System crashed before Debian init.

**Kernel Config**
https://pastebin.com/QjnVN9sZ

[Snap from Error Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/641A4.jpg)

Comment: You'd better report this on https://bugzilla.kernel.org/  and if possible use git bisect to help find the bad commit

Comment: Ty 4 Reply I reported it & hope 4 a solution